# How to use Cube Texture in WebGl

Tags: webgl

recently I have been suffering from unpack 6 images from single environment texture for rendering reflection pass.

[SOURCE IMG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58528830/skybox_texture.jpg)

It turns out in webGl it is difficult to use texImage2D in this kind of job, since texImage2D doesn't provide xoffset, neither yoffset. Granted copyTexImage2D and texSubImage2D did provide offset parameters, however, by using those two functions never run for me

Finally, I found the solution by render the image into canvas then pass the canvas to texImage2D.
 [RENDER RESULT](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58528830/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-21%20at%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%886.34.12.png)

But I got annoying texture seam on the screen. How did that happen and how can I fix it? Thanks guys.

```
        var texture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);



        var myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        myCanvas.width = 512; 
        myCanvas.height = 512;
        var myCanvasContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d"); // Get canvas 2d context

        myCanvasContext.drawImage(_this._data.image, 1024, 512, 512,512,0,0,512,512);         
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvas);

        myCanvasContext.drawImage(_this._data.image, 0, 512, 512,512,0,0,512,512); 
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvas);

        myCanvasContext.drawImage(_this._data.image, 512, 1024, 512,512,0,0,512,512); 
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvas);

        myCanvasContext.drawImage(_this._data.image, 512,0, 512,512, 0,0,512,512); 
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvas);

        myCanvasContext.drawImage(_this._data.image, 512, 512,512,512,0,0,512,512); 
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvas);


        myCanvasContext.drawImage(_this._data.image, 1536, 512,512,512,0,0,512,512); 
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvas);
```

_this._data.image is the environment image; and each texture block is 512X512.

Comment: Your image links are unavailable (looks like a hotlink rejection, but I can't read it). Please re-upload the images using our own image hosting (using the image button in the question editor) — you can't currently embed the images directly but you can link to them.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried but it tells me 10 reputation is needed. Is there any other way?

Comment: I re-uploaded by using dropbox. Hope it works

Comment: plz check [this](http://www.studyjs.com/webgl/texture.html) to understand how a texture is added to canvas in WebGL